# Or'ing function parameters c++

Tags: c++, function, flags

I have noticed that many functions take parameters or "flags" like so:

```
foo(BIG | RED | SWEET);
```

Where `BIG`, `RED`, and `SWEET` have been `#define`'ed earlier in the file such as:
`#define BIG 0x1`

I want to implement my own functions that take parameters like above but I am worried that `OR`ing two numbers together might equal the same result as `OR`ing two different numbers. What is the proper way to define these variables so there is no collision?

Comment: These are bitwise ORs. So the variables are usually zero and powers of 2. 0, 1, 2, 4...

Answer (score 0):

Usually the flags will be powers of 2, ensuring that each combination is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The following powers of 2 hex pattern is commonly used to avoid collisions with flags:

```
#define A    (0x0000)
#define B    (0x0001)
#define C    (0x0002)
#define D    (0x0004)
#define E    (0x0008)
#define F    (0x0010)
#define G    (0x0020)
#define H    (0x0040)
#define I    (0x0080)
#define J    (0x0100)
...
```

Or better yet, use enums:

```
enum Flags
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1 << 0,
    C = 1 << 1,
    D = 1 << 2,
    E = 1 << 3,
    F = 1 << 4,
    ...
}
```

This C++ approach far is more pleasing to the eyes than those hex defines

Comment: You certainly should advise for usage of `enum` instead of a bunch of `#define` directives!

Comment: Ha! Good grief!  Updated.

Comment: `0x0000` is not a power of two. It is not possible to recover your A flag from a resulting bitset.

Comment: That's why 0 traditionally refers to no flags set.

Comment: @bstar55 in that case you could just use `if(!flags)`, instead of the more convoluted `if(flags|A==A)` or `if(flags==A)`

Comment: Yep, your absolutely correct.